# using the sed command: match between 2 regular expressions

Tags: regex

The syntax for this is:

```
sed -n '/Regex1/,/Regex2/p'
```

But this includes the lines where Regex1 and Regex2 are found, how can I exclude them?

For example:

```
abcd-Regex1

BlaBlaBla

abcd-Regex2
```

Then I only want: `BlaBlaBla`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple state machine in `awk`:

```
pax> echo 'abcd-Regex1
BlaBlaBla
abcd-Regex2' | awk '/Regex2/{e=0}{if(e){print}}/Regex1/{e=1}'

BlaBlaBla
```

It basically uses an echo flag `e`, with the commands below executed in sequence for each line:

- `/Regex2/{e=0}` turns echo off when terminating line found.
- `{if(e){print}}` prints line if echo is on.
- `/Regex1/{e=1}` turns echo on when initialising line found.

---

If you *must* use only `sed`, there *is* a way you can do it by passing it through another `sed` to delete the start and end lines:

```
pax> echo 'asdf
abcd-Regex1
BlaBlaBla
abcd-Regex2' | sed -n '/Regex1/,/Regex2/p' | sed -e '/Regex1/d' -e '/Regex2/d'

BlaBlaBla
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but just out of curiosity: is there a way to do it whit the 'sed' command?

Comment: Not that I know of. That doesn't mean it _can't_ be done, just that _I_ don't know how to. And, given that it's pretty unusual to find a system with `sed` but no `awk`, I'd rather just use the tool more suited for the job.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll keep searching :)

Comment: @3sdmx, there _is_ a `sed`-only solution if you're interested (or don't have `awk` for some reason), see the update.